# Is this logically and syntactically correct -- Nested Fact?

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I am trying to write the rule that D is my(me's) son-in-law if they are male and my daughter is the spouse of D. I do not get any errors when I run this on swish except for a few singleton variable warnings. Still, i'm not convinced I wrote this correctly..can someone clarify for me if this even makes sense? Thank you.

```
male(X).
male(me).
female(X).
child(X,Y).
spouse(X,Y).

daughter(A,me) :-
    female(A), child(me, A).
mother(A,me) :-
    female(A), child(me, A).
son_in_law(D,me) :-
    male(D), spouse(daughter(A,me), D).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fact is an **always** true predicate. So,

```
male(X).
```

means that **every** `X` is a male. Clearly, not a correct axiom for your domain. When you get the warning about the singleton `X`, you should not ignore it, but attempt to understand what it means.

Also, syntactically, nested predicates don't make sense. You should rewrite this clause

```
..., spouse(daughter(A,me), D).
```

'lifting up' the 'join' variables, for instance

```
..., daughter(A,me), spouse(A, D).
```